# Integral Representation of Product of Matrices

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Working on Matrix Concentration for Products, I stumbled upon:

$$ 
A^n=\beta_n \int_0^{\infty} t^n \frac{1}{t+A}dt
$$
where A is a complex, square matrix.

I assume t in the denominator means t*identity matrix and every entry of our resulting matrix is to be integrated individually.   
Does $\frac{1}{t+A}$ refer to the inverse matrix?
What is $\beta_n$ and where does this formula come from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you find it ?.

Comment: I found this here: K. Ball, E. A. Carlen, and E. H. Lieb. Sharp uniform convexity and smoothness inequalities for trace norms

Comment: I'll check it. Thanks.